# need help to set message in modal dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I need some help.  I'm trying to dynamically set a message in a modal.  The modal will be used for several different messages depending on the httpErrorResponse returned from my api.  I feel like the {{ }} in html is the way to go but not sure.  Can anyone give me pointers or advise on how to accomplish this?

sign-form.component.ts

```
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Sign} from '../sign';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {PalModal} from '@pallet/angular';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){};
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-form',
  templateUrl: './sign-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-form.component.scss']
})

export class SignFormComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getStoreNumber();
  }

  submitted = false;

  model = new Sign( '', '' );

  @ViewChild( 'modalId', {static: false} ) myModal: PalModal;
  this: any;
  
  ngOnInit() {

  }


  getStoreNumber() {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(
        (params: ParamMap) => {
          this.model.store = params.get( 'store' );
        }
    )
  }

  getSign() {
    this.submitted = true;
    // const {model: model, myModal:  http} = this;
    const sign = this.model;
  

    const STORE_REGEXP = /^-?\d{3,4}$/;
    const PRODUCTID_REGEXP = /^[-0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;

    if (!sign.store
        || !sign.productId
        || !STORE_REGEXP.test( sign.store )
        || !PRODUCTID_REGEXP.test( sign.productId )) {
      return;
    }

    const store = sign.store.length === 3 ? '0' + sign.store : sign.store;
    let productId = sign.productId.toUpperCase();
    const SKU_REGEXP = /^[-0-9]+$/;
    let productType;
    if (SKU_REGEXP.test( productId )) {
      productType = 'sku';
      productId = productId.split( '-' ).join( '' );
    } else {
      productType = 'model';
    }

    const component = this;
    // const url = environment.digitalSignageServiceUri + '/ESL/pdf/store/' + store + '/' + productType + '/' + productId;

    this.http.get<any>( environment.digitalSignageServiceUri + '/ESL/pdf/store/' + store + '/' + productType + '/' + productId )
        .subscribe(
            data => component.route.paramMap,
            

            error => {
              component.myModal.open()
            }
      )
      

    // if (Error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
    //   if (Error.status == 404) {
    //     this.myModal.open();
    //   }
    // }
    //   // window.open( url, '', '' );
    //   let pdfWindow = window.open("");
    //   // let data = " ";
    //
    //   let data: string;
    //   pdfWindow.document.write( "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " +
    //     encodeURI(data) + "'></iframe>" )
  }

        onClick()
    {
      this.myModal.close()
    }
  }
```

sign-form.component.html

```
<div class="container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <form>
        Enter your store number and appliance model ID or SKU to generate an appliance sign
    </form>
    <br>
    <form class="form-store" #signForm="ngForm">
        <pal-text-input label="Store Number" placeholder="XXXX"
                        required
                        pattern="\d{3,4}"
                        size="4"
                        [(ngModel)]="model.store"
                        name="store"
                        #store="ngModel"
                        [invalid]="store.invalid && (store.dirty || store.touched)"
                        invalidText="Enter a valid 4-digit store">

        </pal-text-input>
    </form>

     <br>
    <form class="form-model">
        <pal-text-input label="Model ID or SKU" placeholder="Enter model ID or SKU"
                        required
                        pattern="[\d-za-zA-Z]+"
                        [(ngModel)]="model.productId"
                        name="productId"
                        #productId="ngModel"
                        [invalid]="productId.invalid && (productId.dirty || productId.touched)"
                        invalidText="Enter a valid model ID or SKU">
        </pal-text-input>
      </form>
    <br>
    <div class="button">
        <pal-button size="medium" (click)="getSign()">Generate Appliance Sign</pal-button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modal1">
        <pal-modal #modal1>
            <div slot="header">
                <h3>{{modal-title}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div slot="body">
                {{errorMessage}}
            </div>
            <div slot="footer">
                <pal-button size="small" type="primary" (click)="onClick()">Close</pal-button>
            </div>
        </pal-modal>
        </div>
        
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell us where exactly you are facing the issue? you already know the right way to print the message on html side(using {{}} ). Then where does the problem lies exactly, Is there any error generated using that?

Comment: not getting an error.  on the component side, i am not sure how to pass it over to the html side.  probably needs to be somewhere around the:
```
this.http.get<any>( environment.digitalSignageServiceUri + '/ESL/pdf/store/' + store + '/' + productType + '/' + productId )
        .subscribe(
            data => component.route.paramMap,
            

            error => {
              
                  
              component.myModal.open()
              
                
            }
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for this? It will become easier for us to understand and debug the code.

Comment: One more thing I noticed is, you have used ```modalId``` but there is not template variable with that name. Please update it to 'modal1'

Comment: never created a stackblitz before.